# Como escrever este código MySQL corretamente?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou tentando me adaptar ao mysqli_ visto que o mysql_ pode ser a qualquer momento descontinuado agora que surgiram novos conceitos como mysqli_ e pdo. Estou tentando escrever este script que puxa as informações do banco de dados mas não está funcionando. O que pode estar errado?

```
        <select id="rsvpQuem" name="rsvpQuem">
            <option value="">Selecione uma opção...</option>
            <?php
            $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_convidados";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);

            while($row = $result->fetch_array()){ ?>
                <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['nome']?></option>  
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

Deixando uma solução para meu problema para futuras consultas, acabei usando PDO conforme foi indicado por motivos de segurança e facilidade. Abaixo o código:

```
        <select id="rsvpQuem" name="rsvpQuem">
            <option value="">Selecione uma opção...</option>
            <?php
                $consulta = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_convidados');
                $consulta->execute();
                while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<option value=".$linha['id'].">".$linha['nome']."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro.

Comment: No select aparecem varias linhas de options vazias? testou a consulta direto no banco?

Comment: use essa classe é muito boa.
leia o README e veja os exemplos mais básicos.
https://github.com/offboard/Class-Query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere `$result = $mysqli->query($query);` para `$result = mysqli::query($query);`. Mas recomendo o uso de PDO, devido a maior segurança que irá adiquirir.

Comment: meu Dreamweaver está apontando um erro na linha referente ao código `$result = $mysqli::query($query);`

Comment: é sem $. assim `$result = mysqli::query($query);`

Comment: Acabei usando PDO conforme recomendado e já funcionou. Agradeço a todos do SO pela disposição e ajuda que todos oferecem aos iniciantes em programação.

Answer (score 2):

Sem o erro fica dificil de ajudar, mas parece que você esta utilizando a função errada para percorrer o resultado.

Tente trocar o `$resultado->fetch_array()` para `$resultado->fetch_assoc()`

Documentação:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php